# How to create a sum of unique number and frequency

Tags: sql

Using SQL I want a report that shows how many unique calls and how many total calls was received for a given LinkedUserMailboxName. I'm unable to create a sum for 'Unique Numbers' in the query. Please help.

```
select count(*), UMADUserAccounts.Country as 'Country',
UMADUserAccounts.RankLevel as 'Level',
LinkedUserMailboxName,
CallingNumber as 'Unique Numbers',
count(callingnumber) as 'How many times' 
from UMCallDataRecord 
inner join UMADUserAccounts on 
UMCallDataRecord.LinkedUserMailboxName = UMADUserAccounts.EmailAddress  where 
CallType = 'callansweringvoicemessage' 
and 
[date] between '2019-05-01' and '2019-05-31' 
group by UMADUserAccounts.Country,
UMADUserAccounts.abcRankLevel,
LinkedUserMailboxName,
CallingNumber 
order by 
UMADUserAccounts.Country asc


Expected Output
Country Level LinkedUserMailboxName   Unique Numbers   How many times
USA Associate   Alexia.b@ca.abc.com         2               2
USA Associate   Angelina.asas@de.abc.com    2               2
USA Associate   Asad.slob@ca.abc.com        2               2
USA Associate   Austin.jones@ca.abc.com     3               3
USA Associate   Bankole.smith@ca.abc.com    3               13


Output
Country Level   LinkedUserMailboxName      Unique Numbers   How many times
USA Associate   Alexia.b@ca.abc.com         +11232561600            1
USA Associate   Alexia.b@ca.abc.com         +11235712476            1
USA Associate   Angelina.asas@de.abc.com    +49132433113287         1
USA Associate   Angelina.asas@de.abc.com    daniel.boy@abc.com      1
USA Associate   Asad.slob@ca.abc.com        +11255722196            1
USA Associate   Asad.slob@ca.abc.com        terry.q.public@abc.com  1
USA Associate   Austin.jones@ca.abc.com     +11239840743            1
USA Associate   Austin.jones@ca.abc.com     +11239543735            1
USA Associate   Austin.jones@ca.abc.com     +11234325015            1
USA Associate   Bankole.smith@ca.abc.com    +112355810290           1
USA Associate   Bankole.smith@ca.abc.com    +11233508936            1
USA Associate   Bankole.smith@ca.abc.com    +11237477000            11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `count(distinct)`:

```
select count(*), ua.Country as Country, ua.RankLevel as Level,
       LinkedUserMailboxName,
       count(distinct CallingNumber) as Unique_Numbers,
       count(*) as how_many_times
from UMCallDataRecord cdr inner join
     UMADUserAccounts ua
     on cdr.LinkedUserMailboxName = ua.EmailAddress 
where cdr.CallType = 'callansweringvoicemessage' and
      cdr.[date] >= '2019-05-01' and 
      cdr.[date] < '2019-06-01'
group by ua.Country, ua.abcRankLevel, LinkedUserMailboxName,
order by ua.Country asc;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Qualify all column references, particularly when the query refers to more than one table.
- I removed the `between` for the date comparisons.  Aaron Bertrand has a good [explanation](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) of why you should avoid `between` in this case.